how to fix these npm install errors
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.12.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@9.5.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || >=8.0.0" from @eslint-community/eslint-utils@4.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@eslint-community/eslint-utils
npm ERR!     @eslint-community/eslint-utils@"^4.4.0" from @typescript-eslint/utils@7.12.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/utils
npm ERR!       @typescript-eslint/utils@"7.12.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.12.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!         @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^7.10.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@typescript-eslint/type-utils)
npm ERR!     @eslint-community/eslint-utils@"^4.2.0" from eslint@9.5.0
npm ERR!   peer eslint@">=7.0.0" from eslint-config-prettier@9.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-prettier
npm ERR!     peerOptional eslint-config-prettier@"*" from eslint-plugin-prettier@5.1.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier
npm ERR!       eslint-plugin-prettier@"^5.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     eslint-config-prettier@"^9.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (eslint-plugin-prettier, the root project)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.12.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!   @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^7.10.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@8.57.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.12.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!     @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^7.10.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 

i tried these
npm audit fix npm audit fix --force npm install typescript npm install eslint

Updateeslint and then install --legacy-peer-deps  also clear npm cache and then npm  installI think it should work.

The plugins you're using require eslint 8, but you have eslint 9 installed. Downgrade eslint or find newer versions of your plugins. BugHunter's suggestion is a bad one because it ignores this problem.
